# Do the SE sites incentivize employers to hire lazy employees?

Tags: discussion, jobs

At company A, a lazy employee posts a question every time he runs into a stumbling block. At companies B, C, and D compulsively hard-working employees answer those questions as part of their SE engagement. Can we conclude that SE promotes the hiring of lazy (yet savvy) employees more than otherwise?

Comment: Compared to what?

Comment: @random Compared to a universe without SE.

Comment: "lazy (yet savvy)" sounds like [Smart and Gets Things Done](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/05.html), I wouldn't be surprised if these folks are preferred

Comment: Could also have phrased this as "Do the SE sites incentivize employers to hire effective employees?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct cause & effect relationship between a Q&A site and employment of lazy (yet savvy) people.

Rationally, employers would hire people who answer a lot of questions correctly not users who ask an astronomical amount of questions. That is, given same amount of salary.

But since many companies hire people at different levels, people who know how to quickly acquire knowledge the right way is still preferred over those who don't.

Comment: I was going to compare this question to a question such as 'would a large scale landslide from a very tall mountain increase the number of crocodiles in the river beneath'. But decide such a comparison is too deep for some people to comprehend.

Answer (score 5):

The Stack Exchange network promotes quality questions and answers.

I have encountered some users of these sites that seem to post a question every time they run into a stumbling block.

However, the posters of such questions, which will lack evidence of research effort, should expect to see their questions heavily downvoted, and possibly closed (if warranted).

Consequently, such users should either learn to ask quality questions, or find the sites not to be useful to them, and leave.

When such poor question askers appear to thrive on a site, I think it is a strong indication that a community has not yet fully understood how the focussed Q&A format of Stack Exchange sites works.

Comment: But in practice this is not what happens. Poorly researched questions are marked as duplicates, which only aids and encourages "lazy serial askers".

Comment: If they are only marked as a duplicate then that would encourage "lazy serial askers".  It is heavy downvoting of lazy looking questions that should be the deterrent to their askers.